# Modifying DataTable which is part of DataSet in C# - changes not showing in DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I'm working in C# and I have a `DataSet` and a `DataTable`. I've added the `DataTable` to the `DataSet`. Then I populate the `DataTable` with a SQL query. In the debugger, I can see data in my `DataTable`. I see my `DataTable` in the DataSet's list of tables, but it's a `null` table (i.e., no columns, no data). Why is the data not showing up?  Here's my code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("BaseData");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
List<SqlParameter> paramz = new List<SqlParameter>();
paramz.Add(new SqlParameter("@LitHoldDetailsID", litHoldDetailsID));
dt = LHClassLibrary.LHDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect("usp_GetLitHoldDetails_A", paramz);
```

I've tried

```
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

but that doesn't help. Do I really have to to define all the columns in the DataTable ahead of time? This is a query that returns a large number of columns, so I'm hoping I can skip that step.

Comment: Your `ExecuteSelect("usp_GetLitHoldDetails_A", paramz)` return empty table.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I get data in the DataTable, but if I examine the DataSet, I don't see anything.

Comment: Are you sure that your `LHClassLibrary.LHDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect` doesn't create a new datatable?. If this is true then the object dt is no more the same object you have inserted in the dataset

Comment: At first `ds.Tables[0]` and `dt` refer to the same dataTable. By assigning `dt = LHClassLibrary.....ExecuteSelect(....)` this pointer refers to another (new) table object. So if you inspect `ds.Tables[0]` afterwards you won't see any changings - IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to change the order of your code execution in this way

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
List<SqlParameter> paramz = new List<SqlParameter>();
paramz.Add(new SqlParameter("@LitHoldDetailsID", litHoldDetailsID));
DataTable dt = LHClassLibrary.LHDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect("usp_GetLitHoldDetails_A", paramz);
dt.TableName = "BaseData";
if(dt.DataSet != null) dt.DataSet.Tables.Remove(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

I suppose that the ExecuteSelect method will initialize and returns a DataTable with all the columns and rows returned by your stored procedure.

Only at this point the DataTable is added to your DataSet, not before.
In your code, the variable `dt` is assigned to a DataTable returned by ExecuteSelect but this is not the same reference to the DataTable created before and thus your DataSet remains with an empty table.

Comment: Just for the record, this returns an exception, "DataTable already belongs to another DataSet". bkmtan's solution, above, seems to be the way to go.

Comment: This happens probably because the code inside ExecuteSelect append the table returned to an internal dataset. If you follow the accepted answer then you can forget to use the ExecuteSelect with its facilities to use parameters and you need to code everything by yourself. I have updated my answer to show you a method to remove the datatable from its original dataset

Comment: Of course, if you only want to use the datatable to fill some grid or to do internal elaboration you don't need to append the a dataset and you could work directly with the datatable.

Comment: Steve - thanks - I'm going to go with your solution over bkmtan's because it allows me to use our LHDataAccessLayer class. Why have a class if you're not using it, right? Thanks very much!

Comment: I think that we, as programmers, should try to avoid to repeat ourselves. That's the point. We must try to make the most of the code that we already have.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use SqlAdaptor.Fill(DataTable) like such:

```
string sql = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sql);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter("<sql query>", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adaptor.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do it this way; hope this helps!

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConString))
{
    string command = "Your Query Here...";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", SqlDbType.Type).Value = YourParameter;

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```